# Master-details: how to notify master RecycleView activity of change that requires reloading

Tags: java, android, master-detail

Master-details in Android:

I have a RecycleView in the MainActivity with a row for every item. When the user clicks a row a Details Activity is loaded where he can change stuff.

The thing is, as I go back to the main Activity with:

```
finish()
```

I have to refresh the RecycleView's adapter on the MainActivity's onResume method:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.d("onResume", "yes");

    super.onResume();

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This feels like a waste as not always change has occur (very unbudhistic, I know).

What are my other options going back to the activity "beneath"? Should I use Intent to go back to the MainActivity? Should I use a singleton to pass a didChange flag? Maybe have a didChange flag on the model which I pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start your detail Activity with `startActivityForResult` and set there RESULT_OK if item was changed, then notify adapter in `onActivityResult` only if this flag is set. Also instead of calling `notifyDataSetChanged` you can call [notifyItemChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int))